# What's does the recursive parameter mean in as.character function?

Tags: r, recursion

My R code like this:

```
as.character(c(x[1],recursive = TRUE))

as.numeric(c(x[2],recursive = TRUE))
```

I really don't know what's the meaning of the `recursive` parameter. Sometimes, I eliminate this parameter and lead to some error message, but sometimes are normal. I can't find any help information in R, so I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Try to be more specific, i.e. please post a [**minimal, reproducible example**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) with a relevant set of `x`, together with the error message. Also read [about getting help in R](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Getting-help).

Answer (score 1):

It is a parameter of the `c` function:

> `recursive` logical. If `recursive = TRUE`, the function recursively
>   descends through lists (and pairlists) combining all their elements
>   into a vector.

It is essentially the same as calling `unlist` on `x[1]`. It would only have an effect if the elements of `x` are list like objects.